# CSS3 and progressive enhancement in the wild

Tags: progressive-enhancement

I was wondering if anyone knows of any large sites that use progressive enhancement/CSS3?

I am trying to put a case together at work on why sites don't need to be a carbon copy in all browsers but my arguements will be somewhat impotent without examples in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.headscape.co.uk/ use CSS3 properties while ensuring that their website degrades nicely in browsers that don't support CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.piccsy.com/everything-design/ 
http://www.soleilnoir.net/believein/
 sites use CSS3 transitions but they work fine in IE too apart from the smooth transitioning effects.Comprehensive fallbacks can be written in place for CSS3 properties.

For animation effects that use jQuery libraries animation enhancement plugin are advised.

Many major sites though use advanced properties will write comprehensive fallbacks in javascript so that the incompatible browsers will render the same effect but this can be detected when only one views the source code.